# pass in props to vue-router, with boostrap-vue b-nav-item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to change my SPA from being modals that load components into routed pages that load components. I can open a page using `to="/fixtures"` in the html but I can't pass in a component that has a prop with some data. How do I pass a prop of `fixtures` using vue-router and the bootstrap-vue `<b-nav tabs> <b-nav-item>`?

Home.vue NOT WORKING:

```
<b-nav-item to="/fixtures" :fixtures="fixtures">Fixtures</b-nav-item>
```

index.js from router:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "@/components/Home.vue";
import Scorers from "@/components/Scorers.vue"
import LeagueTable from "@/components/LeagueTable";
import Fixtures from "@/components/Fixtures";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new VueRouter({


  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/fixtures",
      name: "Fixtures",
      component: Fixtures,
      props: true
    }

  ],
  mode: "history"
});
```

Using modals this method works:

```
<b-tab title="Fixtures">
      <Fixtures :fixtures="fixtures" />
    </b-tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass props as part of the route, use this:

```html
<b-nav-item :to="{ path: '/fixtures', props: { fixtures: fixtures } }">Fixtures</b-nav-item>
```

Comment: still doesn't work, in my Fixtures.vue file I'm receiving the prop of fixtures as a watch:{}, then doing some methods to create a new array to then v-for loop over a table, can you see here in the components folder? This component works with modal but not with router https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-carson-sm9j0

Comment: you might need to make the `:to` a computed prop.. but not positive off hand.